# Differences and Similarities Between Lumen and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I read the documentation and it seems Lumen is Laravel with less features. I must be missing something.
I am looking for a comparison table of the components and features of both Laravel and Lumen. Does anyone know the differences?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Laravel is a full-featured framework where as Lumen is touted as a micro-framework derived from Laravel by sacrificing some of it's configurability and extensibility.

Comment: Lumen is pretty much Laravel with less features. That's the point.

Comment: http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/introduction

Comment: https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-lumen

Answer (score 198, accepted):

### Update (5.2)

With the latest version of Lumen (5.2) the Microframework focuses on Stateless APIs.
The [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#5.2.0) states:

> Lumen 5.2 represents a shift on slimming Lumen to focus solely on serving stateless, JSON APIs. **As such, sessions and views are no longer included with the framework.** If you need access to these features, you should use the full Laravel framework.

---

### Original answer (<= 5.1)

**Lumen is all about speed**. It's faster and can handle more requests per second than Laravel.

Laravel is a framework that glues together a lot of components (3rd party and Laravels own components). Now Lumen makes use of a lot of the same components, but strips down the bootstrapping process to a minimum. You could say it is a "different glue", the components (and therefore a lot of the features) are mostly the same.

The performance improvement is achieved by taking away some of the flexibility of the framework in terms of configuration and altering the default boot process.

Besides that, more features are disabled by default and have to be activated before they can be used. As an example: **Facades** (like `DB::table()`)
You first need to uncomment this line in `bootstrap/app.php` to enable them:

```
// $app->withFacades();
```

The same goes for Dotenv environment files and Eloquent.

For routing Lumen uses [nikic/FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) instead of symfonys router because it performs a lot better and gives the micro-framework another big boost.

Other than that pretty much everything is the same as in Laravel.

**Good reads on Lumen**

- [Documentation](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs) (especially the [introduction](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/releases))
- [Article from Matt Stauffer](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-lumen-from-laravel)
- [Interview with Taylor Otwell](https://laravel-news.com/2015/04/lumen/) (especially the last question)
- [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/32kajb/lumen_php_microframework_by_laravel/)
- [Laracast: Introducing Lumen](https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-lumen)

Comment: Would it be that speedy if we'll start uncommenting stuff to get features back?

Comment: @SamDark Obviously it will get a bit slower with every feature you enable. But it will still be pretty fast since the disabled features are just one piece of the performance optimizations

Comment: So benchmark doesn't reflect overhead in real apps and in real apps it will be higher. OK.

Comment: @SamDark [This blog post](http://taylorotwell.com/how-lumen-is-benchmarked/) explains how it was benchmarked. As you can see the test application just returns "Hello World" without using models or other framework features, so the performance in a real application will be slower (although not noticeably in most cases. your application will still be ridiculously fast)

Comment: @lukasgeiter so as I understand it if I'm building an Ionic app with a RESTful Laravel API it would make more sense to use Lumen?

Comment: @mtpultz That's hard to say without more information. However, Lumen usually is great for APIs. I suggest you start with Lumen. If you hit any limits it's very very easy to switch to Laravel.

Comment: @lukasgeiter with the [changes in Lumen 5.2](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#5.2.0), could it be worth noting that Lumen is moving more in the direction of stateless APIs. Where as Laravel is for full service applications. E.g. Sessions/Views being removed from Lumen in 5.2

Comment: Is there a difference now since you can enable and disable middleware for a route group since Laravel 5.2?

Comment: Would be nice to see an update regarding the similarities and differences between Laravel and Lumen for version 8.x.

Answer (score 48):

Lumen is not designed to replace Laravel, rather, it is a more specialized (and stripped-down) framework designed for micro-services and APIs. It took away unneeded features for an API such as HTTP sessions and cookies, and also limited the number of configuration options. **Out-of-the-box, Lumen sacrified the flexibility of Laravel for speed.**

However, you can add Laravel components to Lumen to extend it, so it *can* be used for more than just micro-services and API. However, if your goal is to extend Lumen to become a website, you might as well use Laravel instead.

They also have different use cases. Lumen and Laravel are meant to work together. For APIs and services are frequently get called, use Lumen. For user-facing applications, use Laravel.

---

This answer is taken from a [blog post](http://blog.danyll.com/introduction-to-lumen/) I wrote that explains the difference between Lumen and Laravel.

Comment: As far as I know, cookies, sessions etc are still in there. However they will be lazy loaded and only really affect performance when used.

Comment: Lumen is my preferred framework now. I don't use Eloquent (or any ORMs), so Lumen fits me really well.

Comment: Let's say that I am building a web application and decide to write an API to further separate logic (and to allow easily third party applications). Would it be good practice to write the API with Lumen and write the website with Laravel?

Comment: It is a replacement. It's Laravel with a different router. Virually nothing was stripped out - just made optional. There's no legitimate reason to use Laravel when a supposedly faster Laravel (Lumen) is available.

Answer (score 15):

Quote from Matt Stauffer

> Lumen has the same foundation as Laravel, and many of the same components. But Lumen is built for microservices, not so much for user-facing applications (although it can be used for anything.) As such, frontend niceties like Bootstrap and Elixir and the authentication bootstrap and sessions don't come enabled out of the box, and there's less flexibility for extending and changing the bootstrap files.

You can read more [here](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-lumen-from-laravel)

Comment: In addition, Lumen does not use Symfony's Routing component. Instead, nikic/fast-route is used for greater performance.

Comment: Matt Stauffer's [bower setup](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/convert-laravel-5-frontend-scaffold-to-bower) for Laravel defeats the purpose of the default Bootstrap UI stuff in Laravel anyways, and as for Elixir, that's an `npm install` so it's not completely ready "out-of-the-box" I'd say. So we don't lose much in regards to these, by switching to Lumen. In Lumen, I just create a package.json and npm install Elixer, and setup bower and done...

Comment: However, after using Lumen, I can tell you there are frustrations. So far I've discovered that many of the request/routing/helpers are incomplete compared to what's available from Laravel. For example, you can't do a `redirect()->intended`. I'm hoping Lumen will catch up in these areas. I really like a Laravel without ORM (Eloquent) and so Lumen is very appealing to me.

Comment: @prograhammer, I don't think that that particular feature will ever be included in Lumen. I think that that would require a session which Lumen intentionally does away with. Additionally, I don't see much use for `redirect()->intended()` with an API, which is what Lumen focuses on.

Comment: Lumen is for APIS not for frontends

Answer (score 8):

### [Laravel `9.x`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/) and [Lumen `9.x`](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x)

#### Routing

##### Basic

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `GET` | `Route::get($uri, $callback)` | `$router->get($uri, $callback)` |
| `POST` | `Route::post($uri, $callback)` | `$router->post($uri, $callback)` |
| `PUT` | `Route::put($uri, $callback)` | `$router->put($uri, $callback)` |
| `PATCH` | `Route::patch($uri, $callback)` | `$router->patch($uri, $callback)` |
| `DELETE` | `Route::delete($uri, $callback)` | `$router->delete($uri, $callback)` |
| `OPTION` | `Route::option($uri, $callback)` | `$router->option($uri, $callback)` |
| Multiple HTTP verbs | `Route::match($types, $uri, $callback)` | [image: ns] |
| All HTTP verbs | `Route::any($uri, $callback)` | [image: ns] |

##### Redirect Routes

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | `Route::redirect($from, $to, $status);` | [image: ns] |
| Premanent | `Route::permanentRedirect($from, $to);` | [image: ns] |

##### View Routes

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | `Route::view($from, $to);` | [image: ns] |

##### Route Parameters

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parameters | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Parameters & Dependency Injection | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Required Parameters | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Required Parameters | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Regular Expression Constraints | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Global Constraints | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

##### Named Routes

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | `Route::get($uri, $callback)->name('profile')` | `$router->get($uri, ['as' => 'profile', $callback])` |
| Generating URLs To Named Routes | `route('profile')` | `route('profile')` |
| Inspecting The Current Route by Name | `$request->route()->named('profile')` boolean | [image: ns] |

##### Route Groups

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Middleware | `Route::middleware($middleware)` | `$router->group(['middleware' => $middleware], $callback)` |
| Controllers | `Route::controller(ProfileController::class)` | [image: ns] |
| Subdomain Routing | `Route::domain('{account}.example.com')` | [image: ns] |
| Namespaces | `Route::namespace($namespace)` | `$router->group(['namespace' => $namespace], $callback)` |
| Route Prefixes | `Route::prefix('admin')` | `$router->group(['prefix' => 'admin'], $callback)` |
| Route Name Prefixes | `Route::name('admin.')` | [image: ns] |

##### Route Model Binding

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Implicit Binding | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Implicit Enum Binding | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Explicit Binding | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

##### Fallback Routes

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | `Route::fallback()` | [image: ns] |

##### Route Caching

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Middleware

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Defining Middleware | `artisan make:middleware` | Manual |
| Global Middleware | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Assigning Middleware To Routes | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Middleware Groups | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Middleware Parameters | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Terminable Middleware | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### CSRF Protection

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

*CSRF removed since Lumen version `5.2`*

---

#### Controllers

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Defining Controller | `artisan make:controller` | Manual |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Single Action Controllers | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Controller Middleware | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Resource Controllers | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Dependency Injection & Controllers | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Requests

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Accessing The Request | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Request Path & Method | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Request Headers | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Request IP Address | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Content Negotiation | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| PSR-7 Requests | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Retrieving Input | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Determining If Input Is Present | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Merging Additional Input | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Old Input | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Cookies | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Input Trimming & Normalization | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Retrieving Uploaded Files | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Moving Uploaded Files | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Response

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Attaching Headers To Responses | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Attaching Cookies To Responses | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Redirects | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| View Responses | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| JSON Responses | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| File Downloads | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| File Responses | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Views & Blade

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Blade | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Session

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

*Session removed since Lumen version `5.2`*

---

#### Validation

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Form Requests | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| The `$this->validate` Method | [image: ns] | The `$this->validate` helper which is available in Lumen will always return a JSON response with the relevant error messages. This is in contrast to the Laravel version of the method which will return a redirect response if the request is not an AJAX request. Since Lumen is stateless and does not support sessions, flashing errors to the session is not a possibility. Unlike Laravel, Lumen provides access to the `validate` method from within Route closures. |
| The `exists` And `unique` Rules | [image: ns] | If you would like to use the `exists` or `unique` validation rules, you should uncomment the `$app->withEloquent()` method call in your `bootstrap/app.php` file. |
| The `$errors` View Variable | [image: ns] | Lumen does not support sessions out of the box, so the `$errors` view variable that is available in every view in Laravel is not available in Lumen. Should validation fail, the `$this->validate` helper will throw `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException` with embedded JSON response that includes all relevant error messages. |

---

#### Errors & Logging

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Error | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Logging | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Artisan Console

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Running Commands | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Writing Commands | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Cache

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

*Before using the `Cache` facade, be sure you have uncommented the `$app->withFacades()` method call in your `bootstrap/app.php` file.*

###### Redis Support

Before using a Redis cache with Lumen, you will need to install the `illuminate/redis` package via Composer. Then, you should register the `Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider` in your `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
$app->register(Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);
```

If you have not called `$app->withEloquent()` in your `bootstrap/app.php` file, then you should call `$app->configure('database');` in the `bootstrap/app.php` file to ensure the Redis database configuration is properly loaded.

---

#### Compiling Assets

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mix | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Events

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

###### Generators

In Lumen, there are no generator commands to generate events and listeners for you, so you should simply copy the `ExampleEvent` or `ExampleListener` classes to define your own events and listeners. These example classes provide the basic structure of every event and listener.

###### Registering Events / Listeners

Like the full Laravel framework, the `EventServiceProvider` included with your Lumen application provides a convenient place to register all event listeners. The `listen` property contains an array of all events (keys) and their listeners (values). Of course, you may add as many events to this array as your application requires:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\ExampleEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\ExampleListener',
    ],
];
```

###### Firing Events

You may use the `event` helper function or `Event` facade to fire events throughout your Lumen application. Again, these functions behave exactly like their full Laravel framework equivalent:

```
event(new ExampleEvent);
Event::dispatch(new ExampleEvent);
```

---

#### Authentication & Authorization

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Authentication | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Authorization | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

###### Authentication

Authentication in Lumen, while using the same underlying libraries as Laravel, is configured quite differently from the full Laravel framework. Since Lumen does not support session state, incoming requests that you wish to authenticate must be authenticated via a stateless mechanism such as API tokens.

###### Authorization

###### Defining Abilities

The primary difference when using authorization in Lumen compared to Laravel is in regards to how abilities are defined. In Lumen, you may simply use the `Gate` facade in your `AuthServiceProvider` to define abilities:

```
Gate::define('update-post', function ($user, $post) {
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
});
```

###### Defining Policies

Unlike Laravel, Lumen does not have a `$policies` array on its `AuthServiceProvider`. However, you may still call the `policy` method on the `Gate` facade from within the provider's `boot` method:

```
Gate::policy(Post::class, PostPolicy::class);
```

###### Checking Abilities

You may "check" abilities just as you would in the full Laravel framework. First, you may use the `Gate` facade. If you choose to use the facade, be sure to enable facades in your `bootstrap/app.php` file. Remember, we don't need to pass the `User` instance into the `allows` method since the currently authenticated user will automatically be passed to your authorization callback:

```
if (Gate::allows('update-post', $post)) {
    //
}

if (Gate::denies('update-post', $post)) {
    abort(403);
}
```

Of course, you may also check if a given `User` instance has a given ability:

```
if ($request->user()->can('update-post', $post)) {
    // The user is allowed to update the post...
}

if ($request->user()->cannot('update-post', $post)) {
    abort(403);
}
```

---

#### Database

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic Queries | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Query Builder | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Eloquent ORM | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Migrations | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Seeders | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

*If you would like to use the `DB` facade, you should uncomment the `$app->withFacades()` call in your `bootstrap/app.php` file.*

---

#### Email Verification & Resetting Passwords

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Email Verification | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Resetting Passwords | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Encryption & Hashing

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Encryption | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |
| Hashing | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

*You should set the `APP_KEY` option of your `.env` file to a 32 character, random string. If this value is not properly set, all values encrypted by Lumen will be insecure.*

---

#### Mail

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

---

#### Queues

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

*Closure jobs are not supported by Lumen.*

###### Generators

Lumen does not include generators for automatically creating new Job classes. Instead, you should copy the `ExampleJob` class that is included with the framework.

###### Dispatching Jobs

Again, you should consult the full Laravel queue documentation for complete information on dispatching queued jobs; however, just like in the Laravel framework, you may use the `dispatch` function to dispatch jobs from anywhere within your Lumen application:

```
dispatch(new ExampleJob);
```

Of course, you may also use the `Queue` facade. If you choose to use the facade, be sure to uncomment the call to `$app->withFacades()` in your `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
Queue::push(new ExampleJob);
```

---

#### Service Container

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

###### Accessing The Container

The `Laravel\Lumen\Application` instance is an extension of `Illuminate\Container\Container`, so it may be treated as the service container for your application.

###### Resolving Instances

To resolve things out of the container, you may either type-hint the dependency you need on a class that is already automatically resolved by the container, such as a route Closure, controller constructor, controller method, middleware, event listener, or queued job. Or, you may use the `app` function from anywhere in your application:

```
$instance = app(Something::class);
```

---

#### Testing

| Features | Laravel | Lumen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | [image: ns] | [image: ns] |

Answer (score 4):

Lumen microframework is a lightweight version of Laravel full-stack framework. Lumen use the Laravel syntax and components, and can be 'upgrade' easily to Laravel.

Lumen is a more specialized (and stripped-down) framework designed for Microservices development and API development. So, some of the features in Laravel such as HTTP sessions, cookies, and templating are not needed and Lumen takes them away, keeping what's essential - routing, logging, caching, queues, validation, error handling and a couple of others.

Answer (score 2):

Lumen it's a micro-framework that has the same foundation as Laravel, and many of the same components.

- But Lumen is built for microservices, not so much for user-facing applications.
- It's a massively stripped down version of Laravel, so it took away unneeded features for an API such as HTTP sessions and cookies, and also limited the number of configuration options.
- Lumen makes use of a lot of the same components, but strips down the bootstrapping process to a minimum.
- Its designed to be a lightweight API handling system so you want the code to boot up as quick as possible and to be able to return data back to the user as quick as possible.

**To make it short**

- You have the same route management and the same MVC functionality, you have middleware functionality including throttling, but things like Eloquent are switched off by default although there is a setting to switch it on - its not like it has to be added via composer for example.
- Also you don’t get things like tinker added in and the artisan command.

**Some of the major differences**

- Laravel is a full-stack web application framework that packages or supports a lot of third-party tools and frameworks, whereas Lumen is a micro-framework that is used to develop microservices and API development with the intent of providing speed and high response time.
- Laravel requires different kinds of configuration for the server, and other tools to be used along with the application, whereas Lumen micro framework is a light form of Laravel version that provides specialized features such as API development, cookies, templating, caching, logging, routing, HTTP sessions etc.
- Laravel can be integrated with a different more number of tools than Lumen, whereas Lumen has fewer integration facilities with other tools.
- Laravel performance will be good in the case of SQL queries and tuning the database from the application level, whereas Lumen’s performance declines in the case of SQL queries and fewer features compared to Laravel.
- In Lumen if you need Eloquent you have to enable it.
- In Lumen you don't have Blade template engine.
- Laravel is good for building RESTful APIs (Application Programming Interfaces), whereas Lumen is one of the highest performing micro-framework API for building microservices.
- Authentication in Lumen, while using the same underlying libraries as Laravel, is configured quite differently from the full Laravel framework. Since Lumen does not support session state, incoming requests that you wish to authenticate must be authenticated via a stateless mechanism such as API tokens.
- Lumen has no inbuilt event queuing feature as Laravel has.

Answer (score 0):

**Why Lumen ?**

> Lumen is the perfect solution for building Laravel based micro-services and blazing fast APIs. In fact, it's one of the fastest micro-frameworks available. It has never been easier to write stunningly fast services to support your Laravel applications. [Doc](https://lumen.laravel.com/)

Lumen is a framework to build APIs, which will essentially serve JSON responses for your requests. That's it.

**These kinds of applications are known as web services in general**.

As of Lumen 5.2 update, it doesn't support laravel views, sessions etc... for that you will have to upgrade to full laravel framework.

Some components of the Laravel framework is swapped with other packages in favour of performance. [check them here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.7/composer.json)

**Example scenarios where we can consider Lumen**

- You might want to open up some features of an application to other developers via API
- Your application needs to support both web and mobile application, then it will be perfect to store the data in a DB wrapped in Lumen API.
- When you consider scalability as an important point, you may need lumen

Answer (score -3):

The main difference between laravel and lumen is, Laravel can have artisan commands, which lumen doesn't have.

Comment: This is not true, or at least not up to date. I don't know much about older versions, but I installed lumen 7.x and I have artisan commands