# What is the difference between laravel and lumen

Tags: laravel, frameworks, laravel-5

Taylor Otwell recently released a new framework called Lumen. I am a big user of Laravel.

Can any one point out the difference between Laravel and Lumen micro framework.

What is micro framework all about and when should one use it.

Comment: Your question about the definiton of a microframework can be found in the below link hope it will help you. [stackoverflow definition of microframework](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141495/what-is-a-microframework)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences and Similarities Between Lumen and Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647960/differences-and-similarities-between-lumen-and-laravel)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71257986/984422

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel is doing quite a lot of initialization during each request. With Lumen processing each request is much faster so it is supposed to be able to handle even more load than Laravel with all its caching.

This means that Lumen is less configurable but is able to handle more requests per second.